# How to attach file to windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Is it possible to attach a flat file to windows-service?

My windows-service uses few flat file (for data purposes). Usually, if it's a normal executable I would place those files in the same directory as exe. How can I achieve that with windows-service?

I've done some research on this, but all I found was:
1. Pass a path to those files as a parameter to windows-service.
2. Make a fixed path and just require those files there

But I don't like those solutions. I was wondering if it's possible to attach those files to the windows service while installing it?

Comment: What do you mean "attach"? Can the file contents change? If so, how is somebody going to find the file? It sounds like you want option 2, but also don't want it?

Comment: Don't believe this is possible. You can't "attach" a file to an exe either. But both can look in a specific folder on the computer for the file. Just make sure it has the correct permissions for the account that's accessing it (configurable in service properties).

Comment: @itsme86 Maybe, I could add those text files into VS solution as resources. So then, when the service is installed (InstallUtil.exe MyService.exe) those files will be automatically pasted where the service is?

Comment: What's stopping you from putting the file in the same directory as the executable, same as with a desktop application?  (You're not putting your executable into a system folder, are you?  Because you're not supposed to do that.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm simply calling "Installutil.exe MyService.exe" - I have no idea, where windows is putting my exe file.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding these files inside the project as **Embedded Resources**? They won't show up on the disk, but you could still properly read them from inside the assembly itself.

Here's some reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/kb/319292

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the directory that your application is installed in at runtime, using the `Application.StartupPath` property from `System.Windows.Forms`.  This works for both applications and services.  You should avoid hard-coding the path that you *think* your application is installed in, because the end user may have installed it somewhere else.  You should also avoid using the current directory (i.e., opening the file by name only, without a specific path) because the user may be running your application with a different current directory.

Note that `installutil` does not make a copy of your service executable.  So the service runs from the same directory that it was in when you installed it, and any files you place in that directory should still be there when the service is running.